# QT Opengl Always Giving Black Screen

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

When i run, it's always giving black screen. I do not understand why. Also there is no error output. 
Here is the code ,

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QOpenGLWindow>
#include <QSurfaceFormat>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QtOpenGL>
#include <GL/glu.h>

class MainWindow : public QOpenGLWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();


protected:
    virtual void initializeGL();
    virtual void resizeGL(int w, int h);
    virtual void paintGL();
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event);
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);

private:
QOpenGLContext *context;
QOpenGLFunctions *openGLFunctions;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**I've tried lots of other projects and i'm always gettin black screen. I've tried codes from QT documentation, it worked. But in my code, i could'nt do it.**

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
{
    setSurfaceType(QWindow::OpenGLSurface);

    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CompatibilityProfile);
    format.setVersion(2,1);
    setFormat(format);

    context = new QOpenGLContext;
    context->setFormat(format);
    context->create();
    context->makeCurrent(this);

    openGLFunctions = context->functions();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}

void MainWindow::initializeGL()
{

}

void MainWindow::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{

}

void MainWindow::paintGL()
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);
    glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.5f);
    glVertex2f(0.5f, 0.5f);
    glVertex2f(-0.5f, 0.5f);

    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}

void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{

}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    paintGL();
}
```

What is my problem?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I know what you're trying to do but... in the `MainWindow` constructor you create a new `QOpenGLContext` and initialize it.  But you don't associate it in any way with the `MainWindow` itself.  At the very least I suspect you're initializing one context and trying to draw into another.

Comment: I just wanna see the drawing things on the output. I know mistakes can be made, coz i just started to cpp and opengl via qt.

Comment: The you should take the advice suggested by @simurg and start with one of the [examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-widgets-opengl.html).  Then modify it to do whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is missing `initializeGL`, `renderGl`, `paintGL` functions. You'll have to implement them. Try copying the examples first.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I don't understand that. u mean in .pro file? here is my libs = LIBS     += -lopengl32 -glu32 -lglut

Comment: No, I mean your (ie) `initializeGL` function is empty. You have to initialize OpenGL in this function.

Comment: i did like this, void MainWindow::initializeGL()
{

    QOpenGLFunctions *f = QOpenGLContext::currentContext()->functions();
            f->glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            f->glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

} but still same. Did i missing something? If you give me an example code, i can understand easily. I just started to cpp.

Comment: I thought you said code examples from Qt's documentation worked. Can't you just take one of them as a start point and then modify it according to your needs?

Comment: Thx for all replies and advice. Let me try.